# How can I simplify the following sum : $\sum_{k=0}^{N}{\binom{mk}{j}\binom{N}{k}x^{mk}y^k}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

$j,m,N\in\mathbb{N}^\ast$, and $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^\ast_+$.

Any help or tips will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that e general formula does exist. In any manner, this looks like hypergeometric functions.

There are quite clear patterns for
$$f_m=\sum_{k=0}^{N}{\binom{mk}{j}\binom{N}{k}x^{mk}y^k}$$
$$f_1=\binom{0}{j} \, _2F_1(1,-N;\frac{1-j}1;-x y)$$
$$f_2=\binom{0}{j} \,
   _3F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{2},-N;\frac{1-j}{2},\frac{2-j}{2};-x^2 y\right)$$
$$f_3=\binom{0}{j} \,
   _4F_3\left(\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3},\frac{3}{3},-N;\frac{1-j}{3},\frac{2-j}{3},\frac{3-j}{3};-x^3 y\right)$$
$$f_4=\binom{0}{j} \,
   _5F_4\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{2}{4},\frac{3}{4},\frac{4}{4},-N;\frac{1-j}{4},
   \frac{2-j}{4},\frac{3-j}{4},\frac{4-j}{4};-x^4 y\right)$$

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to try establishing a recurrence relationship, although I'm not too familiar with hypergeometric functions (here's hoping that Wikipedia helps).